# Type Any has no subscript members while adding an array to [String: Any] in Swift3

Tags: swift, swift3

In my `Swift3` code I have an array:

```
var eventParams =
[    "fields" :
        [ "photo_url":uploadedPhotoURL,
            "video_url":uploadedVideoURL
        ]
]
```

Later on I want to add another array to this array, I thought I could just do:

```
eventParams["fields"]["user_location"] = [
            "type":"Point", "coordinates":[appDelegate.longitude, appDelegate.latitude]
        ]
```

but I'm getting error here:

```
Type Any? has no subscript members
```

How can I add that array to my previously declared array `fields`?

Comment: Please attempt to some [basic searching on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Type+Any%3F+has+no+subscript+members) before posting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your dictionary is declared as `[String : Any]`, the compiler doesn't know that the value for "fields" is actually a dictionary itself.  It just knows that it's `Any`.  One very simple way to do what you're trying is like this:

```
(eventParams["fields"] as? [String : Any])?["user_location"] = [
        "type":"Point", "coordinates":[appDelegate.longitude, appDelegate.latitude]
    ]
```

This will just do nothing if `eventParams["fields"]` is nil, or if it's not actually `[String : Any]`.

You can also do this in a couple steps to allow for troubleshooting later on like this:

```
//Get a reference to the "fields" dictionary, or create a new one if there's nothig there
var fields = eventParams["fields"] as? [String : Any] ?? [String : Any]()

//Add the "user_location" value to the fields dictionary
fields["user_location"] = ["type":"Point", "coordinates":[appDelegate.longitude, appDelegate.latitude]]

//Reassign the new fields dictionary with user location added
eventParams["fields"] = fields
```

Comment: Thanks man, I tried your solution (the first one so far) and I'm getting the following error: `Cannot assign to immutable expression of type Any?` :(

Comment: I also tried the 2nd approach, and the middle line esp. `eventParams["fields"]["user_location"]` causes error same as before, `Type Any? has no subscript members`

Comment: @user3766930 I'm sorry - I had a mistake in there.  Try the 2nd option again based on my edits.

Comment: Thanks for your patience :) However, right now I see this error http://imgur.com/XpbUxJW , is there some typo maybe?

Comment: @user3766930 My bad again - sorry.  Try one more time.